# CSS Responsive Content Alignment

Tags: html, css

I try to redesign my website with device compatibility.

I use this code for min-width768px which means desktop or laptop devices.

```
    <div style="width:100%;">
    <div style="width:20%; height:60px; margin-top:10px; float:left;">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" width="155" height="60" alt="Logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu" style="width:70%; height:50px; margin-top:25px; font-size:12px; float:left;">
        <ul class="yatay_menu">
        <li>
        <a href="#" title="Anasayfa">/a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="kurumsal.php" title="Hakkımızda"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu" style="width:10%; height:80px; margin-top:20px; float:left;">
        <img src="images/telefon.png" width="147" height="40">
    </div>
    <div class="responsive_menu"><i class="fa fa-bars" style="color:#b0063a; font-size:28px;"></i></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

In compatibility version of this code I hide menu and phone number divs. Instead of them until 480px I show another div which is a contains bars icon.

```
.menu { display:none; }    
.responsive_menu { display:block; width:80%; margin-top:25px; }
```

What i want is this icon has to align right side of div. However it isn't work. I use float right but it isn't displayed beacause dimension of page. Image is exactly explain the issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting the parent element to width 100%;?

Comment: for reference that bar icon is referred to as a hamburger menu

Comment: also i hope that witdh is just a misspelling here and in the actual code its width

Comment: I tried parent div width 100% still doesn't work. I fix misspelling issue actual code is same.

Comment: there's several solutions i can propose, but itd be helpful to have more css and html (maybe even a fiddle) that would demonstrate your line of thinking, only need enough for the nav and the responsivness

Comment: do you have all the html? i don't know what .responsive_menu refers to, or what element is the bar icon is either..... its important to give the minimumm code needed to reproduce your error, or else it'll just be guess work

Comment: @Daemedeor I update the question with all code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to remedy this.

using divs with percentage widths on devices that scale is asking for problems, especially if there is content overflow on them.

The safest way to do this, is to use absolute positioning for the menu button.
Something like this :

```
#menuButton
{
   position:absolute;
   top:15px;
   right:10px;
}
```

This makes the element titled 'menuButton' positioned from the right, ensuring it's always on the right side of your view.

Comment: actually absolute, doesn't move with the window (SO's menu for reference is absolute), the position: fixed, does. However, that will cause problems when the person decides to scroll down.

Comment: though that can be solved by making the title bar responsive i suppose

Comment: You have a point. but since there's no indication at all that OP wants it to move along with the window, i didn't bother with it.
If you did want that, you'd probably want the entire header using `position:fixed` instead.

Comment: true, there's too little code to really give a good solution -.-"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fixed edit: i'd propose just giving your menu icon a position: fixed; when displayed. The draw back is that you'd need the title bar fixed as well....

```
#menu_icon{
   position: fixed;
   right: 15px;
}
```

OR you can give the parent containing div width: 100%; and then give the icon absolute right: 15px; like, this is better overall, imo:

```
.responsive_menu{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu_icon{
   position: absolute;
   right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: `.responsive_menu { display:block; width:80%; position: absolute; float:left; right: 5px; margin-top:25px; }` now it works. thank you guys.

Comment: Float is useless with a position absolute.

Comment: Also, that is basically my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use the most popular HTML, CSS, JS Framework which provides responsive containers applicable for your mobile. http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Just telling the asker to use any framework is not an answer.

Comment: it's just a suggestion sir.

Comment: In order for this to be a good answer, you'd need to explain to the asker how they could use said framework to solve their problem. ideally with an example.